# Horizontal Output C++

Tags: c++

the codes below represent output of coordinates,for example it'll show faces_x=201 etc. However,they are all displayed vertically. How to print them on the console horizontally?

```
printf("faces_x=%d\n", faces[i].x);
printf("faces_y=%d\n", faces[i].y);
```

Comment: Remove the `\n`s?

Comment: Alternative: `std::cout << "faces_x=" << faces[i].x << " faces_y=" << faces[i].y;` Some delimiter, a space or a newline most likely, may be needed on the end to distinguish one set of data from the next.

Comment: thanks for the constructive inputs, it helped me alot. thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply remove the newlines, i.e. `\n`, the 2 lines will be printed horizontally:

```
printf("faces_x=%d", faces[i].x);
printf("faces_y=%d", faces[i].y);
```

Note that your question doesn't actually need the second `\n` to be removed, unless you want the following output to start on a new line.

Comment: sorry for a simple question as im not really good at this, you are a life saviour.